# PHP: Scheduling jobs with shell_exec and qsub

Tags: php, queue

I'm trying to use PHP's `shell_exec` to enqueue a job. I'm using [this](https://github.com/alexanderrichard/queueing-tool) queueing tool. A simple

```
qsub testscript.sh
```

on the command line works fine, but when I call

```
shell_exec("qsub testscript.sh")
```

nothing happens. I already tried setting full permissions (777) both to the qsub executable itself and to the testscript file, but it didn't help. I'm having trouble understanding where the error happens.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Just setting the file permissions might not be enough, if it's outside of the root directory that PHP is in.  Often on C-Panel PHP runs as the C-panel user for the site which means it's locked into the home directory of the user, or at least I found that to be the case on some servers.  You could rule this out by using something like `file_exists()` in PHP to see if it can see the file.  But this is just a wild guess...

Comment: `$output = shell_exec("qsub testscript.sh"); echo $output;`

Comment: Redirect stderr and include the error message: `echo shell_exec("qsub testscript.sh 2>&1")`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. With @Peter's suggestions I could make some progress. One of the problems was that the install directory of the queuing tool (`/usr/queue`) was not in the path. Using `putenv` or `export PATH=...` didn't help, but I could get it to run by copying all the queue scripts into the current www directory.

Another problem was that the script relies on python's `os.getenv('USER')`, which is None when called by the server. Modifying that to catch that error solved the issue.